# How Should delete item by id and redirect?

Tags: redirect, yesod

I would like to make a function which deletes a item by id and redirects to user an other page.

`deleteItemR :: ItemId -> Html
 deleteItemR itemid = runDB $ delete itemid 
                      redirect ItemR`

I tried so many times in other ways but it did not work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look like this:

```
deleteItemR :: ItemId -> Handler Html
deleteItemR itemid = do
    runDB $ get404 itemid
    runDB $ delete itemid
    setMessage . toHtml $ ("Item deleted" :: Text)
    redirectUltDest ItemR
```

First, your function signature cannot be `ItemID -> Html`, it must be executed in a `Handler`.

You also need to use the `do` notation to emulate a sequence of actions in Haskell.

Note that any action in such a sequence can end the execution. For example, the `runDB $ get404 itemid` will try to fetch the item referenced by `itemid`. If it does not exist, the user will be redirected to the 404 page (not found) without trying to execute the other actions.

We need the `runDB $ get404 itemid` action because the `runDB $ delete itemid` action will not end the sequence even if the item does not exist. It would therefore indicate an item was deleted though there was none.